# Batch Dissolve Polygons based on Attributes in QGIS or FWTools

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I was wondering if anyone can help with batching a dissolve.  I have a few hundred polygon shapefiles that I want to dissolve based on an attribute.  I would like to do this in QGIS or FWTools.

Answer (score 4):

fTools is a python plugin for QGIS that can do it and you could hack it into fitting your needs.

An easier alternative is the QGIS GRASS plugin, which includes [v.dissolve](http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass63/v.dissolve.html), but then you're easier off scripting with GRASS directly. If you're not familiar with PostGIS, this may be a faster approach.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe load them in postgis and write a small script to do the dissolve.