# How to dissolve polygons and aggregate their data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile (one layer) with my country but I have a problem.

It is divided into 4 entries (prefectures), and I want it as one, not 4.

Also, there is a table with some data, and I want to have one row with the sum of the data. For example:

```
Entry  1: population 10.000, 
entry  2: population 20.000, 
entry  3: population 30.000, 
entry 4: population 40.000.
```

Ultimately I want something similar to  this:

```
main piece: population 100.000.
```

(I don't care if this will be done by hand, its not much work!).

I'm a new QGIS user and i don't know much. Any help would be really appreciated greatly!

Comment: What you are looking for is a dissolve polygons tool.This might help you out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26657/batch-dissolve-polygons-based-on-attributes-in-qgis-or-fwtools

Comment: or this. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/dissolve-ploygons-in-qgis-or-grass-to-new-polygons-of-defined-population-sizes

Answer (score 0):

As said above and in your question the dissolve function is there. try batch dissolve and failing that try some of the solutions in [Dissolve ploygons in QGIS or Grass to new polygons of defined population sizes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31324/dissolve-ploygons-in-qgis-or-grass-to-new-polygons-of-defined-population-sizes)

With dissolve you have an option to dissolve all which may need some basic tidying after the function is complete.

Hope something helps.