# QGIS batch merging grouped layers

Tags: qgis, merge, qgis-modeler

I have a situation as you see below:

[image]

I have imported the .dxf file from AutoCAD, which finally looks like the above. Each layer includes lines and polylines. I need to have them merged with each other.

I found some similar problems here:

[Batch process for merging features in multiple layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346769/batch-process-for-merging-features-in-multiple-layers)

[Merging multiple temporal inputs in QGIS Graphical Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394525/merging-multiple-temporal-inputs-in-qgis-graphical-modeler)

which utilizes the graphical modeler.
It does make sense, although I haven't used the graphical modeler so far, therefore I don't know how to start.

Is there a chance to make this merge in one go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are open to a PyQGIS solution, it can be done very simply:

```py
p = QgsProject.instance()

# get all layers in project
lyrs = p.mapLayers().values()

# filter layers if necessary (could also filter by geometry type)
line_layers = [x for x in lyrs if 'line' in x.name().lower()]

# merge layers (don't forget to specify your coordinate system)
merged = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':line_layers,'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']

# add to canvas
p.addMapLayer(merged)
```

To merge layers per group (using the hierarchy in your screenshot):

```py
# reference to the project
p = QgsProject.instance()

# reference to the layer tree
root = p.layerTreeRoot()

# reference to the group called 'Batch'
group = root.findGroup('Batch')

# loop through all the items in the Batch group
for child in group.children():
    # find sub-groups
    if isinstance(child, QgsLayerTreeGroup):      
        sub_group = child
        
        # empty list to store the layers ready to merge
        lyrs_to_merge = []

        # find line layers in the sub-group
        for sub_child in sub_group.children():
            # check whether the child is a layer and has 'line' in its name
            if isinstance(sub_child, QgsLayerTreeLayer) and 'line' in sub_child.name().lower():
                lyr = sub_child
                # add to list
                lyrs_to_merge.append(lyr.layerId())
        
        # perform merge
        merged = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers", {'LAYERS':lyrs_to_merge,'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']    
        
        # name the merged layer
        merged.setName('merged | ' + sub_group.name())
        
        # add layer to project, but prevent adding to canvas and layer tree (with False) 
        p.addMapLayer(merged, False)
        
        # insert the merged layer at the top of each sub-group
        sub_group.insertLayer(0, merged)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It works, but I need to have it merge not as a whole, but within the given group. How could I change the code?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: I see no reaction. Shall I select some particular layer for it?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the resulting layer tree. Each sub-group has a merged layer inserted at the top.

Comment: I see nothing executed in my QGIS, although he code looks fine. Your answer has been accepted anyway. I will figure out the error from my side. Thank you!

Comment: What I wondered was whether the "polylines" layers are MultiLineString and the others LineString. In which case, perhaps the merge is failing. You might need to add a 'multipart to singlepart' step before the merge

Comment: It might have a sense. Is there any programmatic way to do it?

Comment: I just tested and it appears to work with a mixture of Lines and MultiLines, so I don't think that's the issue. Other than making sure the names and group/sub-group levels match your screenshot, I really don't know why you're experiencing problems, unfortunately.

Comment: I think I must fix my end this time. Thank you very much for your help :)